# How ambiguity is resolved automatically in multilevel inheritance in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

Java does not support multiple inheritance. One of the reasons is that there could be an ambiguity between methods while inheriting. For example, in the below scenario, there will be an ambiguity to which version of "LevelMethod()" should be inherited in Class “Level3”

```
class Level1{
public void LevelMethod(){
    System.out.println("Level1 method");
 }
}
class Level2{
public void LevelMethod(){
    System.out.println("Level2 method");
 }
}
class Level3 extends Level1,Level2{
}
```

But, same kind of ambiguity might occur in the following scenario through multi-level inheritance to which version of "LevelMethod()" should be inherited in
Class “Level4”.

```
class Level1{
public void LevelMethod(){
    System.out.println("Level1 method");
 }
}

class Level2 extends Level1{
public void LevelMethod(){
    System.out.println("Level2 method");
 }
}

class Level3 extends Level2{
public void LevelMethod(){
    System.out.println("Level3 method");
 }
}

class Level4 extends Level3{

}
```

How java is able to resolve ambiguity in multilevel inheritance, but not in multiple inheritance?

Comment: Why do you think it's ambiguous?  Each method overrides its direct superclass version.

Comment: OP is not saying it is ambiguous, but asking why the same principle cannot apply for multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ambiguity exists when there is no mechanism for conflict resolution.
On single inheritance, the children override the methods on their parents, the method lookup has a clear resolution with no conflicts, since there is an order.

Classic multiple inheritance does not specify conflict resolution mechanism and thus the [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) appears.

FYI other models like [mixins](http://bracha.org/oopsla90.ps) specify a linearization mechanism for implicit conflict resolution, while [traits](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihtMuPyOfLAhUBF5AKHdj9DQ4QFggkMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ptidej.net%2Fcourse%2Fift6251%2Ffall06%2Fpresentations%2F061122%2F061122.doc.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEvmhI6h3GjtXYNw__rVjpMhBECGg&sig2=h1z1iZhRTPrSPmzjIoZx1Q) require you to make explicit the algebra for conflict resolution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Logain. So, Shall I conclude that Java does not support  multiple inheritance because conflict resolution mechanism is not specified in JVM if ambiguity occurs ?

Comment: Multiple inheritance does not imply a mechanism for conflict resolution, on the contrary, when such mechanism exists, we stop calling it multiple inheritance and start talking about mixins or traits. On Java 8 with default methods on interfaces you **do** have the ambiguity problem, and can be seen as a form of multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The method being invoked in the inheritance hierarchy will depend on the object type. Each subclass is overriding the parent's "levelMethod".

Try with a few examples

```
Level1 level = new Level1();
level1.levelMethod(); //Prints "Level1 method"

Level1 level = new Level2();
level.levelMethod(); //Prints "Level2 method"

Level1 level = new Level3();
level.levelMethod(); //Prints "Level3 method"
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Objects in java are nothing but simply references. So, it doesn't matter whether two or more classes having is-a relationship have same method because it'll depend on which object calls the method, because references will be different (identified by their hashCode). in your given code, if object of Level 2 calls the method `LevelMethod()` then the context of class Level 2 is been referred, so evidently Java will interpret results from `LevelMethod()` of Level 2.
But as object of super class can refer object of child class, while calling `LevelMethod()` you'd need to specify of which class.
If you want to prove that references are different then execute this program:

```
class A{
    public void cmethod(){
        System.out.println("Class A");
    }
}
class B extends A{
    public void cmethod(){
        System.out.println("Class B");
    }
}
class C extends B{
    public void cmethod(){
        System.out.println("Class C");
    }
}
class MainClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A aObj = new A();
        B bObj = new B();
        C cObj = new C();
        System.out.println(aObj.toString());
        System.out.println(bObj.toString());
        System.out.println(cObj.toString());    
    }
}
```

Explanation: If you create your own class and don't override the method toString(), then `Object` class will call it's default `toString()` method which displays `Class@refHashCode` (All classes are child class of class `Object`).

Comment: Hi Kamal, why can not Java apply same concept in cases of Multiple inheritance  ? It can call the method depending on which object it called if ambiguity occurs in Multiple inheritance

Comment: Because, the case in which multiple inheritance fails (i.e your first snippet) distinguishing object is not the problem there only one object will be calling but instead distinguishing method will be the problem if method of both the classes have same signature.Hence, due to the fact that not in all cases Java can resolve ambiguity, it doesn't allows at all.